# Combining reduntant rows in INNER JOIN MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to know if it's possible to combine a result of INNER JOIN, without getting duplicate values. Here is my problem:

I've got 2 tables:

```
product
product_id, product_name, image

product_price
product_id, selling_price, mrp
```

When I combine both the table using `INNER JOIN` I get the results combined as expected:

For the query:

```
SELECT `product`.`product_id`, `product`.`product_name`, `product`.`image`,
       `product_price`.`selling_price`, `product_price`.`mrp`
FROM `product`
INNER JOIN product_price ON `product.product_id` = `product_price.product_id`
```

As expected this works fine and I get the result ( vardump() php ):

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'product_id' => string '8' (length=1)
      'product_name' => string 'product1' (length=8)
      'image' => string '587d0e605fb52ed571f80a9e9d0d4cea.png' (length=36)
      'selling_price' => string '100' (length=3)
      'mrp' => string '110' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=6)
      'product_id' => string '8' (length=1)
      'product_name' => string 'product1' (length=8)
      'image' => string '587d0e605fb52ed571f80a9e9d0d4cea.png' (length=36)
      'selling_price' => string '200' (length=3)
      'mrp' => string '220' (length=3)
```

Now as you can see the two rows contain repeated product_id,product_name,image columns, I was thinking if there was a way to avoid this redundancy and some what get the result like :

```
array (size=6)
          'product_id' => string '8' (length=1)
          'product_name' => string 'product1' (length=8)
          'image' => string '587d0e605fb52ed571f80a9e9d0d4cea.png' (length=36)
array (size=2)
0 =>
          'selling_price' => string '100' (length=3)
          'mrp' => string '110' (length=3)

1 => 
      'selling_price' => string '200' (length=3)
      'mrp' => string '220' (length=3)
```

Thanks,
-Sreejith

Comment: Yes. This is simple array manipulation (from single dimensional to multidimensional).

Comment: use distinct or group by

Comment: @Strawberry I want it done on MySQL, I know I can do it via php but I was looking if I could use it by query :)

Comment: In relational databases there's no concept of hierarchies. Each row-column intersection will have a single value and not an array. MySQL has `GROUP_CONCAT` which can merge all group members to a comma separated string but that will still need some PHP manipulation to become an array.

Comment: No. MySQL returns a single dimensional array only. You can do things like pivot the result, but if you've got PHP, why bother?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, and indeed in all relational database management systems, the result of every query is a rectangular table made of rows and columns.  As you know it comes out like this:

```
  product_id   product_name   image     selling_price  mrp
       8         product1     xxx.png     100           110
       8         product1     xxx.png     200           220
       9         product2     aaa.png      17            18
       9         product2     aaa.png      22            24
```

You are asking if MySQL can generate a data structure more like this:

```
  product_id   product_name   image     selling_price  mrp
       8         product1     xxx.png     100           110
                                          200           220

       9         product2     aaa.png      17            18
                                           22            24
```

with itemizations for each distinct product.

The answer is **No, not with just one query**.

You could query the product table, and then for every item in the product table you could query the price table. That would yield the data structure you want. But that's *very* inefficient -- it does too many queries.

You could use a single query, and use ORDER BY to make sure each product's results are in consecutive rows in the result set. Then you could, in your application program, detect those consecutive identical rows.

Reporting systems like Crystal Reports, Jasper, or BIRT do a good job of transforming these rectangular resultsets into nicely presented layouts.

Comment: So if I use a No-SQL Database like MongoDB then may be but not on MySQL like right??